# How to add a floating button on scrolling in android?

Tags: android, button, scrollview

I have a scrollview inside my page and that contains a linearlayout. My requirement is to add a floating button on scrolling this layout and perform actions on this button click. How can this be done. Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps I've misunderstand your question, but it sounds like you want a stationary `Button` outside of your `ScrollView` so that you can scroll and always see the `Button`?

If so, just add the `Button` OUTSIDE the `ScrollView`:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_save"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Save" />

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView_list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Outside the button and scrollview, a relativelayout can be used to wrap. And the Button can be used with android:layout_alignParentBottom="true",android:layout_alignParentRight="true" to align to the rightbottom position of parent.

Answer (score 3):

Use [this library](https://github.com/shamanland/floating-action-button), it has already done things you required.

Include it in your project:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.shamanland:fab:0.0.5'
}
```

Add `FloatingActionButton` to your layout instead of regular `Button`:

```
<com.shamanland.fab.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/button_save"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
```

Link it with `ScrollView`:

```
FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.button_save);
ScrollView scrollView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.scrollView_list);
scrollView.setOnTouchListener(new ShowHideOnScroll(fab));
```

That's all, it should works!

Check my [original post here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25098626/1891118) and look at the [example app](https://github.com/shamanland/floating-action-button/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/shamanland/fab/example/ExampleListActivity.java#L26).