# Android L ripple touch effect on shape?

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

I have a rounded rectangle with elevation that casts a shadow, just like in the example here: http://developer.android.com/preview/material/views-shadows.html#shadows

Here is my shape:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
    <corners android:radius="6dp" />
</shape>
```

I want to get the nice "ripple" touch effect that everything else has, but when that's set as the view's background, no touch feedback is given. The shape stays white.

So, I made it into a `layer-list`:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
            <corners android:radius="6dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:drawable="?android:selectableItemBackground" />
</layer-list>
```

Now I get nice touch feedback when I tap it, but there's a problem.

The outline of the rounded rectangle shape was lost. It still draws the white rounded rectangle fine, but the shadow is cast as a non-rounded rectangle (square edges), and the ripple goes all the way out past the corners:

[image: Bad corners]

It doesn't look too horrible on here, but on the device it's pretty ugly and off-putting.

Is there a way to fix this? The `Outline` section of the first link seems to be what I want, but I can't figure out how to implement it.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Try that one:

ripple.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple android:color="@color/COLOR_WHILE_PRESSING" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <item android:drawable="@drawable/background"></item>
</ripple>
```

background.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <solid android:color="@color/BACKGROUND_COLOR" />
 <corners android:radius="6dp" />
</shape>
```

Or maybe this post will help you: [Android L FAB Button shadow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24480425/android-l-fab-button-shadow/24498041#24498041)

I explained there, how to implement the new FAB button, I also used the outline for that.

Comment: The post you linked helped get the `Outline` working. Now it's perfect, thanks!

Unfortunately putting the `<shape>` as an item in the ripple still makes it think it's a non-rounded rectangle. But using the outline method, it works fine.

Comment: In case anyone else is trying this, I tried the same technique layer-list (referencing a layer-list and wrapping it in a ripple element) and it works nicely.

Comment: But what should be the Target and Min SDK ?

Answer (score 11):

This is with ripple and layer-list.

```
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:color="@color/colorRipple">
<item>
    <layer-list>
        <item>
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="#349F37" />
                <corners android:radius="6dp" />
                <stroke
                    android:width="2dp"
                    android:color="#50E751" />
            </shape>
        </item>
    </layer-list>
</item>

</ripple>
```

Answer (score 5):

```
<RelativeLayout
 android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground">
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: please provide description of your answer

Answer (score 2):

[click here](http://blog.nkdroidsolutions.com/android-ripple-effect-example-code/) for complete source code

Create button.xml in drawable folder

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/colorPrimaryDark"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/colorPrimary"/>
</selector>
```

Create button.xml in drawable-v21 folder

```
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="?android:colorControlHighlight">
    <item android:drawable="@color/colorPrimary" />
</ripple>
```

you can set button.xml as background of your view.

```
<TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:text="Android Ripple Effect Custom"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:textSize="18sp" />
```

if you want custom color for ripple effect instead of default gray, then you can archive it by adding colorControlHighlight in your style.

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```