# Android L's Ripple Effect - Touch Feedback for Buttons - Using XML

Tags: android, xml, android-5.0-lollipop, material-design, rippledrawable

I am trying to understand how to implement the "Ripple Effect - Touch Feedback" for buttons and other views. I looked at the questions related to Ripple touch effect on SO and got some insight into it. I was able to successfully get the ripple effect using this java code.

```
import android.animation.ObjectAnimator;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.graphics.RadialGradient;
import android.graphics.Region;
import android.graphics.Shader;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.animation.AccelerateInterpolator;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MyButton extends Button {

    private float mDownX;
    private float mDownY;

    private float mRadius;

    private Paint mPaint;

    public MyButton(final Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public MyButton(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public MyButton(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs,
            final int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setAlpha(100);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(@NonNull final MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            mDownX = event.getX();
            mDownY = event.getY();

            ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(this, "radius", 0,
                    getWidth() * 3.0f);
            animator.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
            animator.setDuration(400);
            animator.start();
        }
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    public void setRadius(final float radius) {
        mRadius = radius;
        if (mRadius > 0) {
            RadialGradient radialGradient = new RadialGradient(mDownX, mDownY,
                    mRadius * 3, Color.TRANSPARENT, Color.BLACK,
                    Shader.TileMode.MIRROR);
            mPaint.setShader(radialGradient);
        }
        invalidate();
    }

    private Path mPath = new Path();
    private Path mPath2 = new Path();

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(@NonNull final Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        mPath2.reset();
        mPath2.addCircle(mDownX, mDownY, mRadius, Path.Direction.CW);

        canvas.clipPath(mPath2);

        mPath.reset();
        mPath.addCircle(mDownX, mDownY, mRadius / 3, Path.Direction.CW);

        canvas.clipPath(mPath, Region.Op.DIFFERENCE);

        canvas.drawCircle(mDownX, mDownY, mRadius, mPaint);
    }
}
```

But, i want to use XML approach. How do i achieve this? I have looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24527402/android-l-ripple-touch-effect-on-shape) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24480425/android-l-fab-button-shadow/24498041#24498041), but i am not yet that comfortable with styles, so i am finding it difficult to achieve the ripple effect.

I have a button with the following XML code:

```
 <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_email"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.50"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/email" />
```

How do i get ripple effect for this button. If someone can guide me, I will be thankful.

[EDIT] Adding ripple.xml and background.xml, as mentioned in one of the links above. I have created a drawable-v21 folder in res and added the below files there.

ripple.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="@android:color/black" >
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/background">
    </item>
</ripple>
```

background.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <solid android:color="@android:color/darker_gray" />
</shape>
```

I added the ripple as background for my button, here is the xml for my button now..

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_email"
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.50"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/ripple"
    android:text="@string/email" />
```

When i run the application i get a ResourceNotFoundException. Here is the logcat trace..

```
07-21 17:03:39.043: E/AndroidRuntime(15710): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-21 17:03:39.043: E/AndroidRuntime(15710): Process: com.xx.xxx, PID: 15710
07-21 17:03:39.043: E/AndroidRuntime(15710): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #60: Error inflating class <unknown>
07-21 17:03:39.043: E/AndroidRuntime(15710):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
07-21 17:03:39.043: E/AndroidRuntime(15710):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
07-21 17:03:39.043: E/AndroidRuntime(15710):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
07-21 17:03:39.043: E/AndroidRuntime(15710):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
07-21 17:03:39.043: E/AndroidRuntime(15710):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
07-21 17:03:39.043: E/AndroidRuntime(15710):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
07-21 17:03:39.043: E/AndroidRuntime(15710):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
07-21 17:03:39.043: E/AndroidRuntime(15710):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
07-21 17:03:39.043: E/AndroidRuntime(15710):    at com.xx.xxx.BusinessAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(BusinessAdapter.java:106)
07-21 17:03:39.043: E/AndroidRuntime(15710):    at com.xx.xxx.BusinessAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(BusinessAdapter.java:1)
07-21 17:03:39.043: E/AndroidRuntime(15710):    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:2915)
07-21 17:03:39.043: E/AndroidRuntime(15710):    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:2511)
07-21 17:03:39.043: E/AndroidRuntime(15710):    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$RenderState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:1425)
07-21 17:03:39.043: E/AndroidRuntime(15710):    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:999)
07-21 17:03:39.043: E/AndroidRuntime(15710):    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:524)
07-21 17:03:39.043: E/AndroidRuntime(15710):    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:1461)
07-21 17:03:39.043: E/AndroidRuntime(15710):    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:1600)
07-21 17:03:39.043: E/AndroidRuntime(15710):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
07-21 17:03:39.043: E/AndroidRuntime(15710):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
07-21 17:03:39.043: E/AndroidRuntime(15710):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
07-21 17:03:39.043: E/AndroidRuntime(15710):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
07-21 17:03:39.043: E/AndroidRuntime(15710):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
07-21 17:03:39.043: E/AndroidRuntime(15710):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
07-21 17:03:39.043: E/AndroidRuntime(15710):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
07-21 17:03:39.043: E/AndroidRuntime(15710):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
07-21 17:03:39.043: E/AndroidRuntime(15710):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
07-21 17:03:39.043: E/AndroidRuntime(15710):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
07-21 17:03:39.043: E/AndroidRuntime(15710):    at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:374)
07-21 17:03:39.043: E/AndroidRuntime(15710):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
07-21 17:03:39.043: E/AndroidRuntime(15710):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
07-21 17:03:39.043: E/AndroidRuntime(15710):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
07-21 17:03:39.043: E/AndroidRuntime(15710):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
07-21 17:03:39.043: E/AndroidRuntime(15710):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
07-21 17:03:39.043: E/AndroidRuntime(15710):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
07-21 17:03:39.043: E/AndroidRuntime(15710):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1983)
07-21 17:03:39.043: E/AndroidRuntime(15710):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1740)
07-21 17:03:39.043: E/AndroidRuntime(15710):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:996)
07-21 17:03:39.043: E/AndroidRuntime(15710):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5600)
07-21 17:03:39.043: E/AndroidRuntime(15710):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
07-21 17:03:39.043: E/AndroidRuntime(15710):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
07-21 17:03:39.043: E/AndroidRuntime(15710):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
07-21 17:03:39.043: E/AndroidRuntime(15710):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
07-21 17:03:39.043: E/AndroidRuntime(15710):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
07-21 17:03:39.043: E/AndroidRuntime(15710):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
07-21 17:03:39.043: E/AndroidRuntime(15710):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
07-21 17:03:39.043: E/AndroidRuntime(15710):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
07-21 17:03:39.043: E/AndroidRuntime(15710):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-21 17:03:39.043: E/AndroidRuntime(15710):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-21 17:03:39.043: E/AndroidRuntime(15710):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
07-21 17:03:39.043: E/AndroidRuntime(15710):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
07-21 17:03:39.043: E/AndroidRuntime(15710):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-21 17:03:39.043: E/AndroidRuntime(15710): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
07-21 17:03:39.043: E/AndroidRuntime(15710):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
07-21 17:03:39.043: E/AndroidRuntime(15710):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
07-21 17:03:39.043: E/AndroidRuntime(15710):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
07-21 17:03:39.043: E/AndroidRuntime(15710):    ... 50 more
07-21 17:03:39.043: E/AndroidRuntime(15710): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f020075 a=-1 r=0x
```

Comment: you should use `MyButton`, not `Button`

Comment: Ya i dont want to use java code.. I got rhe ripple effect if i use MyButton.. But i want to achieve it using Shapes and Backgrounds.. I hope u got what i meant

Comment: I took a look to one of the link.. It looks trivial, what is your problem? Where is your `ripple` xml?

Comment: According to: https://developer.android.com/preview/material/animations.html#touch you should set button's background to `?android:attr/selectableItemBackground` or `?android:attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless` in your xml code.

Comment: @blackbelt i updated my question with the ripple and background xml, please have a look at it.

Comment: @MichałZ. when i set the background as mentioned in the site, i am not able to see the background at all and no ripple effect either. I tried that before.

Comment: @blackbelt any idea on my updated question?

Comment: @VamsiChalla no I am sorry

Comment: Are you testing on a device running an L preview build?

Comment: please help in creating ripple effect for android pre lollipop devices .

Answer (score 72, accepted):

**UPDATE Material Components:**

With the [Material Components Library](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android) it is very easy to apply a ripple.
Just use the [`MaterialButton`](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/MaterialButton.md) and the **`app:rippleColor`** attribute:

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
    app:rippleColor="@color/my_selector"
    ../>
```

With a selector like this:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <item android:alpha="..." android:color="?attr/colorOnPrimary" android:state_pressed="true"/>
  <item android:alpha="..." android:color="?attr/colorOnPrimary" android:state_focused="true" android:state_hovered="true"/>
  <item android:alpha="..." android:color="?attr/colorOnPrimary" android:state_focused="true"/>
  <item android:alpha="..." android:color="?attr/colorOnPrimary" android:state_hovered="true"/>
  <item android:alpha="..." android:color="?attr/colorOnPrimary"/>

</selector>
```

---

**Old answer**
You can do something like this:

```
<Button
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:background="@drawable/ripple"
      
    />
```

Where the ripple.xml is:

```
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
                      android:color="?android:colorControlHighlight">
        <item android:id="@android:id/mask">
            <shape android:shape="oval">
                <solid android:color="?android:colorAccent" />
            </shape>
        </item>
 </ripple>
```

Comment: i get resource not found for colorControlHighlight and colorAccent, how do i get rid of this?

Comment: I am getting ResourceNotFoundException still. Can i know something? I created a folder drawable-v21 in res and added ripple.xml there. Is that the correct approach?

Comment: You can use your favorite colors of course. Are you using a theme with android:Theme.Material.Light as parent?

Comment: I am testing the app on Nexus 5 with 4.4.4, so i haven't created any values-v21 folder(i guess i don't need drawable-v21 as well). I have added appcompat_v7 for backward support.

Comment: Just realised.. ripple needs minimum api level of 21. But, eclipse didn't throw me error before this.. Now how do i test this on Nexus?

Comment: You can only test this on an Android-L emulator or a Nexus with a flashed Android-L system image.

Comment: U need to use appcompact7 to use accent colors pre API 21. See https://chris.banes.me/2014/10/17/appcompat-v21/

Comment: @BenitoBertoli & gabriele , how can we use ripple ripple-effect in pre lollipop devices .

Comment: @TusharPandey it is not officially supported.

Answer (score 30):

Just put `?attr/selectableItemBackground` in the background of button for API 21+ , like below:

```
<Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:text="Button" />
```

Comment: This answer gives the ripple effect within a rectangle. If you want the ripple effect done in a circle use: `android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"`

Comment: Does this work only for Buttons, or will it work for any View?

Comment: how to set button background if i am using this property??

Comment: In my case, `android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"` worked for Button/ImageButton

Answer (score 20):

For lollipop(API>21) make file as btn_ripple_effect.xml in drawable  and put below code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:color="?android:colorAccent"
    tools:targetApi="lollipop">
    <item android:drawable="@color/cancel_btn_clr" /> <!-- default -->
    <item android:id="@android:id/mask">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="?android:colorAccent" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</ripple>
```

For pre lollipop (API<21)make file as btn_ripple_effect.xml in drawable-v21 folder and put below code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@color/colorAccent"></solid>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item>
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@color/cancel_btn_clr"></solid>
        </shape>
    </item>

</selector>
```

Comment: Might just want to add that I believe the pre-lollipop should be wrapped in `<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">` tags

Comment: API>21 does not equal setting lollipop in targetApi. My advice would be not to set the targetApi in this case.

Comment: that's the opposite folder structure, drawable-v21 is for lollipop and above resources

Answer (score 12):

Slight addition to above answer:  Note that the mask color is not used in any way.

You can do more complicated things with ripple as well. For example, if you wanted a border on your ripple button you can use it like a layer-list.

```
<ripple
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:color="?android:colorControlHighlight">

    <!-- Note: <ripple> acts like a layer-list -->
    <item android:id="@android:id/mask">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <!-- This color is not displayed in any way -->
            <solid android:color="@android:color/black" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <!-- This is the border -->
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="3dp"/>
            <!-- Use your border color in place of #f00 -->
            <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#f00"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
 </ripple>
```

Note that the element with id `@android:id/mask` is only used to show where the ripple effect will stop at. If you wanted it to cover the whole button, you could change the `android:shape` to be `rectangle`. You can imagine doing many more interesting things with this as well!

Also make sure to have a backup drawable for devices that aren't 21 yet or the app will crash on old devices.

Comment: Is it possible to extend the mask outside of the bounds to fake a borderless button?

Comment: @William Is it possible to use ripple effect with ImageButton?

Answer (score 7):

The best way to use this in **android:foreground**, because it allows you use own background also.

> android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"

Example:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:background="@color/button.normal"
    android:textColor="@color/white"/>
```

Comment: You will also have to add `android:clickable="true"` to the view

Comment: @backslashN You are right but it depends on your XML design.

Answer (score 3):

I was researching ripple effect as it was something I wanted to apply to a few buttons in my application and happened across your post. While your question is searching for an answer as to how to add the ripple effect using XML that was actually something I was trying to avoid as when trying to add that attribute you see it requires v21.

If you are targeting lower than v21 than that new class extending Button (or ImageButton, etc.) will avoid complaints from the compiler.

As there was no explanation on how to implement the custom class above I thought I would fill in. All you need to do is create the new class and then in the XML change "Button" to "the.package.name.MyButton".

From:

```
 <Button
    android:id="@+id/Button"     

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

To:

```
 <the.package.name.MyButton
   android:id="@+id/Button"     

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

That's it. Now your button when pressed will have a ripple contained within its bounds.

I like this approach I just wish the ripple would extend pass the bounds. For a small button this ripple effect really highlights how square or rectangular the button really is. Visually it would be more satisfying if the ripple just continued until it reached its full radius.

Answer (score 1):

You can add `clickable` as `true` and `background` or `foreround` as `?attr/selectableItemBackground` attributes to the view:

```
<Button
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="Button"
     android:clickable="true"
     android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
     android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>
```

If in case your view already has a `background` filled with something, you could fill your `foreground` with `selectableItemBackground`

```
<Button
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="Button"
     android:clickable="true"
     android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
     android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
     android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>
```