# Different colored buttons android

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to have 2 different colored buttons for my app. I am currently using this in **styles.xml** but it applies this theme for the whole app:

```
<item name="android:colorButtonNormal">@color/primaryColor</item>
```

I tried using this in the button but it makes no difference,

```
android:backgroundTint="@color/accentColor"
```

Please help! I would appreciate clear answers as I cannot find the answer anywhere. Thanks!!

Comment: Use `android:background="@color/mycolor"` in the xml of each separate button.

Comment: @MatterCat Is it different to backgroudnTint?

Comment: backgroundTint is only available in API level 21+ and from what I can tell, applies more of a filter to the current color than an actual background.

Comment: @MatterCat I'll try it once I get home. And I'm only using my app for Lollipop :D

Comment: @MatterCat In the lollipop emulator, I am not getting any ripple animation for the button. How do I incorporate it? Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24863430/android-ls-ripple-effect-touch-feedback-for-buttons-using-xml