# No ripple on second floating action button in same layout

Tags: android, floating-action-button

I have two floating action buttons in one layout file, but only the last one gets the ripple effect applied. If I place them opposite, then it's also the last one getting the ripple. So no matter how they are placed in the layout file, the last one gets a ripple effect on touch and the other does not.
How can this be? Are there any solution to getting the ripple effect on both FABs?

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab_report"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_fab_run"
    android:elevation="8dp"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/primary"
    app:rippleColor="@color/blue" />
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab_run"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_fab_run"
    android:elevation="8dp"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/primary"
    app:rippleColor="@color/blue" />
```

TL;DR: Only the last one FAB in the layout gets the ripple effect, how to solve this?

Comment: This could be helpful  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24863430/android-ls-ripple-effect-touch-feedback-for-buttons-using-xml

Comment: It seems like the first FAB is not even clickable. Nothing happens on touch.

Comment: It's bad practise to have more than one FAB in view

Answer (score 5):

I don't know the reason, but adding this attribute solved the problem:

```
app:theme="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.ImageButton"
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue - turns out I was implementing a TouchListener for one FAB, and consuming the touch event by returning true from the listener callback. Once I changed this to return false, the FAB ripple effect started working again.