# ripple to an ImageButton not working

Tags: android, android-imagebutton

I am trying to add ripple on my image button but it won't work

> ```
> <ImageButton
>     android:id="@+id/imageButton"
>     android:layout_width="250dp"
>     android:layout_height="60dp"
>     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
>     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
>     android:layout_marginBottom="139dp"
>     android:background="@drawable/googleback"
>     android:scaleType="fitXY"
>     android:src="@drawable/google" />
> ```

This is my ripple code

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
> <ripple android:color="#fafafa">
> <item android:id="@android:id/mask">
>     <shape android:shape="rectangle">
>         <solid android:color="?android:attr/colorControlHighlight" />
>     </shape>
> </item> </ripple>
> ```

Answer (score 1):

1. Your code is incomplete
2. Ripple only works in Android 5.0. Are you sure you're running your app on a 5.0 or newer version of AVD ?

According to [Android L's Ripple Effect - Touch Feedback for Buttons - Using XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24863430/android-ls-ripple-effect-touch-feedback-for-buttons-using-xml), You should set a `Button` ripple effect like this:

```
<ImageButton
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:background="@drawable/ripple"/>
```

**ripple.xml**

```
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
                      android:color="?android:colorControlHighlight">
        <item android:id="@android:id/mask">
            <shape android:shape="oval">
                <solid android:color="?android:colorAccent" />
            </shape>
        </item>
 </ripple>
```

Comment: I have edited my code ..... and yes i am running it on my phone with Android 5.1.1