# Best way to show Ripple effect in Android

Tags: android

I would like to know which is the best way to show ripple effect in Android. It comes by default in buttons and all. But if we try to set the background color of the buttons, the effect will go off.

I saw some [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24863430/android-ls-ripple-effect-touch-feedback-for-buttons-using-xml) in stack overflow itself for creating this effect. But its an old post and Google would have added some new attributes to XML file to generate the effect.

Any help would be much appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create this xml file in your drawable folder, replace the ripple color and name it "ripple.xml":

```
<ripple 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="@color/your_ripple_color">
</ripple>
```

Now you can apply this as a background:

```
android:background="@drawable/ripple"
android:clickable="true"
```

Comment: This won't work for devices running on kitkat and jellybean right?

Comment: Thanks a lot Ziegler.