# Android Ripple Effect for my custom button

Tags: android, button, android-animation, rippledrawable

I have created a project with custom button class as below.

```
package app.kibbeh.widget;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MyFontButton extends Button {
    private static final String TAG = "TextView";
    private Typeface typeface;

    public MyFontButton(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MyFontButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setCustomFont(context, "");
    }

    public MyFontButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        setCustomFont(context, "");
    }


    private boolean setCustomFont(Context ctx, String asset) {
        try {
            if (this.typeface == null) {
                Log.i(TAG, "asset:: fonts/" + asset);
                this.typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(ctx.getAssets(), "fonts/avenirroman.ttf");
            }
            setTypeface(this.typeface);
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e(TAG, "Could not get typeface: " + e.getMessage());
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Now i have to add ripple effect from here. so is it possible or i have to add rippelview in all xml file ? please guide me. 
Thank you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this link for set the ripple effect on button:

[Material effect on button with background color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26686250/material-effect-on-button-with-background-color)

[Android L's Ripple Effect - Touch Feedback for Buttons - Using XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24863430/android-ls-ripple-effect-touch-feedback-for-buttons-using-xml)

Comment: Yes , i have checked it. its work for me. Thank you so much.