# Ripple and Fragment SlideOut Animation

Tags: android, android-animation, ripple, rippledrawable

i got a button which replaces the current fragment with a custom `slidein` - `slideout` animation.

`FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
 ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left);
 ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
 ft.commit();`

On the Button i want to use a ripple like this:

`android:background="?selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"`

Everything technicly works, but you cant see the ripple-animation. You only see it if you press the button very long. The slidein animation starts before the ripple is visible. How can i make the ripple visible?

Comment: UX-wise, as a user I do not care about ripple animation, I need to see the action after my button click. What you want to do, is to make the user wait after click, which is not good.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24866786) about ripple effect.

**Also** notice that ripple effect only works at `API 21` and higher.