# Card view material ripple?

Tags: android, material-design

I'm developing a material design interface. I have cards that I want to have the ripple effect when clicked. I've done what google says and nothing happens. Here's my code:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/card_view"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:elevation="5dp"
            android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground">
            >

            <ImageView 
                android:id="@+id/blue_image"
                android:src="@drawable/blue"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:elevation="8dp"
            />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"    
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:text="And this is a blue card!" 
                android:elevation="10dp"
                />
```

Comment: Try to add `android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"`

Comment: @Skizo now I can click on it and it goes lighter but it doesn't ripple. (I'm on KitKat BTW)

Comment: Have you seen this [question?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26942434/4385913)

Comment: Okay so there's no possible way to make ripples in KitKat?

Comment: Don't think so, I guess ripples are only available on L....

Comment: @Cagentdog You can use custom libraries to implement ripples on pre lollipop versions :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at my example (API<21). It's similiar to Lollipop ripple effect.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=liure-_hlX0&feature=youtu.be

For this demonstrantion i have used this libary:
https://github.com/balysv/material-ripple

just add to build.gradle:

```
 compile 'com.balysv:material-ripple:1.0.1'
```

Selector for Card View (wrapped RelativeLayout): *list_item_selector.xml*:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<!-- Pressed -->
<item android:drawable="@color/ripplecolorbackground" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<!-- selected -->
<item android:drawable="@color/ripplecolorbackground" android:state_selected="true"/>
<!-- focused -->
<item android:drawable="@color/ripplecolorbackground" android:state_focused="true"/>
<!-- default -->
<item android:drawable="@color/transparent"/>
```

*Layout:*

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="5dp"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="3dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="3dp"
    card_view:cardPreventCornerOverlap="true">

    <com.balysv.materialripple.MaterialRippleLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:mrl_rippleColor="@color/rippplecolorlist"
        app:mrl_rippleAlpha="0.10"
        app:mrl_rippleOverlay="false"
        app:mrl_rippleHover="true"
        app:mrl_rippleDimension="1dp"
        app:mrl_rippleDuration="350">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:background="@drawable/list_item_selector"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

            </com.balysv.materialripple.MaterialRippleLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

*Colors:*

```
<color name="ripplecolorbackground">#1A000000</color>
<color name="rippplecolorlist">#26000000</color>
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a library that allows to customize every view without affecting the layout to create the ripple effect

I hope it helps you
https://github.com/xgc1986/RippleViews/blob/master/docs/RippleDrawableHelper.md

Also the sample is using cardViews with this effect ;)