# How to monit the Button Rippe Animation is finished? I think launch or do something after the ripple animation is finished is a better way

Tags: android, animation, material-design

How to monit the Ripple Animation? I think launch or do something after the ripple animation is finished is a better way.

Something like a Listener of Animation Finish.

Because if the Animation is showing and start Activity at the same time, the UE is bad,like something is interrupted or dropping frames.

[Material Design] : The ripple animation is in button or other widgets. I click it and the ripple animation shown.

It's not the button.getAnimation.setAnimationListener().....Because the ripple animation is setted in xml and I think it's a widget property.

Any answers will be appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If it was possible to use a function like "onRippleFinish" or something like that you would have a problem on old Android version that does not have any ripple effect.

If you want to control your ripples on any Android version you can use a lib like that https://github.com/traex/RippleEffect

For more information about standard Androidi ripple you can check this link : [Have a button execute OnClickListener on end of ripple animation(Material theme)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30201422/have-a-button-execute-onclicklistener-on-end-of-ripple-animationmaterial-theme)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I find the lib for a long time. I forgot to star it last time