# Android RippleEffect not shown when setting custom background

Tags: android, android-cardview, ripple

My goal is to create a simple CardView with white background AND having a ripple effect when clicking on it. By just enabling the ripple effect with:

```
android:clickable="true"
android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

The ripple is shown. But at this point, the background is a dark grey. So let's change it to white

```
card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#FFFFFF"
```

Now my CardView is white, but there is no ripple anymore. No matter what I try, either I get only ripple, or only white background.

Hope you can help me!
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check it out for details 
[Material effect on button with background color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26686250/material-effect-on-button-with-background-color)

create a xml drawable and use as your background (API 21+).

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:color="?attr/colorControlHighlight">
        <item android:drawable="?attr/colorPrimary"/>
    </ripple>
```

Comment: Thanks. I created a xml drawable and placed it in the drawable folder. But AndroidStudio won't let me choose this as card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/...". Any ideas?

Comment: set your background with this attr: android:foreground = //ripple bacground sample usage: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30046813/5923606

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks mate!