# Cardview ripple effect doesn't work

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-animation, cardview

Min SDK is 21. When I click on a cardview in my recycler adapter, the ripple effect doesn't happen and just goes to the next screen. The recyclerview is inside a fragment.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/entire_card"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="265dp"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        app:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
        >


        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progressbar"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:paddingTop="120dp"
                android:visibility="visible"/>


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/pet_image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="210dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/placeholder"
                android:visibility="gone"
                 />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/pet_description"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="55dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/pet_image"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:background="@color/primaryColour"
                />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Adapter code where I have my onClick for each item.

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        public TextView petInfo;
        public ImageView imgURL;
        public ProgressBar progressBar;

        private Context itemContext;
        public ViewHolder(View v){
            super(v);
            imgURL = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.pet_image);
            petInfo = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.pet_description);
            progressBar = (ProgressBar) v.findViewById(R.id.progressbar);

            itemContext = v.getContext();

            v.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){

            Intent intent= new Intent(itemContext, DetailCardLayout.class);
            Integer position = getAdapterPosition();
            intent.putExtra("CARDVIEW_POSITION", position);
            v.getContext().startActivity(intent);

        }
    }
```

Comment: Set your CardView as root layout and try.

Comment: That helps! However the ripple effect only works for two clicks. i.e. click a cardview, goes to the next screen and press back. repeat. then when you click a third time no more ripple effect

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26942434/ripple-effect-on-android-lollipop-cardview

Answer (score 11):

Your card view contains relative layout which covers the card view surface, so write ripple effect in relative layout.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView 
    android:id="@+id/cardView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
    app:cardElevation="2dp"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="false"
    app:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    >
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl_bookmark"
        android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"> ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to Add

```
android:clickable="true"
```

to your card view xml

Comment: That seems to help. However, when I scroll to see more (2 cards take up a screen) the ripple effect doesn't seem to work after the first two cards.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your image in a `FrameLayout` with a foreground attribute of:
`android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"`

E.g.

```
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/pet_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="210dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/placeholder"
            android:visibility="gone"
             />

    </FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Another way to solve this: Using a Button Style

Add the Borderless Button Style to the root element of your layout.
There's no need for `focusable` or `clickable` attributes, the default styling encapsulates all that for you.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    style="@android:style/Widget.Material.Button.Borderless"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```

**NOTE**: Add the style to the `ViewGroup` in your `CardView` that houses other views

Answer (score 0):

Just add **background** to your child view inside **MaterialCardView**.

> `android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"`

```
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:background="@color/white">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/item_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    // -> rest of your design

  </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
```