# Setting Ripple effect to RecyclerView CardView item without having to double tap for an item action

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview, ripple-effect

I have a `RecyclerView` with a `CardView` as the root element of the row item layout. I managed to have a ripple effect to `CardView` using below list item layout as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26942434/ripple-effect-on-android-lollipop-cardview/30046813#answer-28041873).

**Row item layout:**

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin_8dp"
    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/cyan"
    app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
    app:cardElevation="5dp">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/transparent"
        android:padding="@dimen/margin_8dp">

            <!-- Underlying views-->

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

The problem is that to have a click action on a row item in the `RecyclerView` adapter requires a couple of taps, the first tap for selecting the item and showing the ripple effect, and the second tap for the actual click to trigger `View.OnClickListener`.

Using `android:focusableInTouchMode = "true"` attribute in `CardView` is the reason for the double tap; but disabling it, also disable the ripple effect consequently.

I tried to use a custom Ripple effect as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26942434/ripple-effect-on-android-lollipop-cardview/30046813#answer-30046813), but doesn't work. Also tried to have the ripple effect on the underlying `CardView` root element as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57585239/ripple-effect-on-androidx-cardview-widget-cardview#answer-57586012), but still nothing new.

Similar thing for using the button style as in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42318410/cardview-ripple-effect-doesnt-work#answer-62033947).

And I have a transnational itemView click listener in `RecyclerView` adapter within the view holder

```
class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    ViewHolder(@NonNull final View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by totally removing `android:focusableInTouchMode = "true"` & `android:foreground` from the `CardView`, and adding the ripple effect to the root item within the CardView with `android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"`

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin_8dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/cyan"
    app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
    app:cardElevation="5dp">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:padding="@dimen/margin_8dp">

            <!-- Underlying views-->

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replaced `View.OnClickListener` with `View.OnFocusChangeListener`, and when the row item gets a focus after it's been clicked, I run the same code as in `onClick` callback.

But that doesn't give the ripple effect a chance to show up, so posted that with some delay.

```
itemView.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (hasFocus)
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // Do whatever done in onClick()
                }
            }, 10); // delay to give the ripple effect a chance to show
    }

});
```

I wish if there's another solution without any delay.