# Change Background of Items on Long Press

Tags: android

I want to change the background of Card View on Long Press and I have visited so many forum but no one gave the proper answer.

So, How to change the background of list/card/recycler view just like the long press on navigation view items ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess, you are trying to implement **Ripple Effect** on CardView. To achieve that, add the following attributes to your CardView in xml:

```
android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
android:clickable="true"
```

Hope this helps. [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28041873/7235049).

Answer (score 0):

If you use `RecyleView`. You have to use `onLongClickListener()` event on `Adapter` of `RecyleView`. Just like -

```
    @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
                final ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) holder;

                //go news details fragment
                holder.newsContentLayout.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onLongClick(View v) {
                    // change you cardview background
                     holder.cvCardView.setImageDrawable(holder.cvCardView.getContext().getResources()
                          .getDrawable(R.drawable.bg_cardview));

                    }
                });
        }
```

If you use `ListView` then you can do it by -

```
listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

          CardView cardView = (CardView)  view.findViewById(R.id.cardview);
            cardView.setBackgroundDrawable(getApplicationContext().getResources().getD    rawable(R.drawable.background));
                    return false;
                }
            });
```