# How to Fill Color in Button from Right to left?

Tags: android

How to change background color of button when click on it like ripple but after filling ripple effect a color of button also change.

**My .xml file**

```
<com.andexert.library.RippleView
        android:id="@+id/more"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        app:rv_alpha="250"
        app:rv_centered="true"
        app:rv_color="#008600"
        app:rv_framerate="20"
        app:rv_rippleDuration="600"
        app:rv_type="rectangle">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:text="Click He"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
</com.andexert.library.RippleView>
```

**My java file**

```
rippleView.setOnRippleCompleteListener(new RippleView.OnRippleCompleteListener() {

            @Override
            public void onComplete(RippleView rippleView) {
                btn.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorBackground));
            }
        });
```

***Here, i change background color in onComplete but it can be possible to change background color with ripple effect???***

Comment: i want to change background color with ripple effect but problem is after ripple effect finish background color is as default color than how to change color with fill effect in button.

Comment: post what you have tried

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24527402/android-l-ripple-touch-effect-on-shape

Comment: i  see but 
how can change background with color of ripple effect.
in this if ripple effect is once finish than it is back to its default background.

Comment: ????????????????????????@Mohit
????????????????????????@MPG