# how to set two xml file together as background

Tags: android, android-studio

i want ripple effect and border around my cardview, and i have two xml file
one for border and other is for riple effect, so how can i set on my cardview as background

here is my code

shape.xml(v17)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
         <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
                 <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#1B5E20" />
                 <corners android:radius="2dp"/>
                 <padding android:left="0dip" android:top="0dip" android:right="0dip" android:bottom="0dip" />
         </shape>
```

ripple.xml(v21)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:color="?android:attr/colorControlHighlight">
     <item
            android:id="@android:id/mask"
            android:drawable="@android:color/white">
     </item>
 </ripple>
```

and here is my cardview that i want to set both thing together..

cardview.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/cardView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

         <RelativeLayout
                android:background="@drawable/shape"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="16dp">

             <TextView
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:id="@+id/title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Title"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

         </RelativeLayout>
     </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

how can i set both file together bcz two background in on layout is not supported. help me, plz.

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24527402/android-l-ripple-touch-effect-on-shape

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do it using layer-list. cardview_style.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<layer-list
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape>
        <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#1B5E20" />
        <corners android:radius="2dp"/>
        <padding android:left="0dip" android:top="0dip" android:right="0dip" android:bottom="0dip" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <ripple
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="?android:attr/colorControlHighlight">
        <item
        android:id="@android:id/mask"
        android:drawable="@android:color/white"></item>
    </ripple>
</item>
```

Then add following file to background attribute.

Comment: my shape has corner radius of 100dp i.e circular corner. How to show the same in case of ripple. ripple seems like a rectangle.

Comment: Great Solution. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Create a new XML with a layer-list and add your shape and ripple in it

Answer (score 1):

Just like Iulian Popescu said you can use layer-list, what seems to be best option. But if you insist to keep that xmls them separatly, than you can always merge them in your code using canvas.
Use this topics if you want to use this techniques:

[How to merge bitmaps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10616777/how-to-merge-to-two-bitmap-one-over-another)

[Converting drawables to bitmaps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3035692/how-to-convert-a-drawable-to-a-bitmap)