# How to use setOutlineProvider instead of setOutline in Lollipop

Tags: android, android-layout, android-5.0-lollipop, material-design, android-appcompat

For the earlier L Preview there were some examples like shown below to add to your code in order to use an FAB (Floating Action Button).

But unfortunately I can't use that same code to implement an FAB due to the setOutline method not being supported anymore, but it appears to have been replaced by an alternative method 'fab.setOutlineProvider(ViewOutlineProvider);'. could anyone explain how to use this?...

It is probably something really simple that I am missing, but any help would be much appreciated.

```
// Outline
int size = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.fab_size);
Outline outline = new Outline();
outline.setOval(0, 0, size, size);

Button fab = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fab);
fab.setOutline(outline);
fab.setClipToOutline(true);
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Just to complete the @ianhanniballake answer:

```
Button fab = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fab);
//Outline outline = new Outline();
//outline.setOval(0, 0, size, size);
//fab.setOutline(outline);  
ViewOutlineProvider viewOutlineProvider = new ViewOutlineProvider() {
        @Override
        public void getOutline(View view, Outline outline) {
            // Or read size directly from the view's width/height
            int size = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.fab_size);
            outline.setOval(0, 0, size, size);
        }
    };
fab.setOutlineProvider(viewOutlineProvider);
```

Comment: You also should check, beforehand, the current version of the device, as this method is only supported after android L.

Answer (score 12):

Per [customizing view shadows and outlines training](https://developer.android.com/training/material/shadows-clipping.html#Shadows):

> You can create oval and rectangular outlines with rounded corners using the methods in the [Outline](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Outline.html) class. The default outline provider for views obtains the outline from the view's background. To prevent a view from casting a shadow, set its outline provider to null.

So your `ViewOutlineProvider` just needs to call `setOval(0, 0, size, size)` on the `outline` parameter to `getOutline()`:

```
public void getOutline (View view, Outline outline) {
    // Or read size directly from the view's width/height
    int size = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.fab_size);
    outline.setOval(0, 0, size, size);
}
```

Comment: What does it do exactly? Show the correct shadow of the view?

Comment: @androiddeveloper - that's correct. By default the shadow is cast using the bounds of your view, which works great for opaque rectangular Views that fill their entire bounds, but obviously not so much for (in this case) circular Views.

Comment: I see. So what should be used if I have a weird shape for a view, or a view that changes its shape ?

Comment: @androiddeveloper - you can set an arbitrary path with [setConvexPath()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Outline.html#setConvexPath(android.graphics.Path)). You can call [invalidateOutline](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#invalidateOutline()) at any time if your View changes shape dynamically and you want the outline updated.

Comment: what about pre api 21?

Comment: @JemshitIskenderov - there's no such thing as elevation pre-API 21, so no shadows and no need for a specific outline.

Comment: @JemshitIskenderov - you'll need to bake in fake elevation and shadows into your background assets then (this is how CardView works, for instance). There is no API support for pre-21

Comment: @ianhanniballake thanks  for response. went with Canvas way

Answer (score 2):

Every View has an Outline object and a ViewOutlineProvider(V.O.P) object. 
As the name suggest viewoutlineprovider provides the outline to the view indirectly.

What the view does is it passes its outline object to the V.O.P and the V.O.P updates it.

so you have the view's Outline object in the getOutline method of the VOP as a parameter,simply update it.

```
ViewOutlineProvider viewOutlineProvider = new ViewOutlineProvider() {
    @Override
    public void getOutline(View view, Outline outline) {
        outline.setOval(0, 0, view.getWidth(), view.getHeight());
    }
};
fab.setOutlineProvider(viewOutlineProvider);
```