# android.view.View Cannot resolve method setOutline(android.graphics.Outline)

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

I'm testing out the samples in the L sdk for Android using Android Studio (latest)

However it can't find the method setOutline() I've looked through the references under android.view.View and there doesn't seem to be a method called setOutline.

I've looked at other L samples and they also use the setOutline method, but there is no android.view.View.setOutline()

Comment: I'm seeing something about it being replaced from the preview by setOutlineProvider(): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26472955/how-to-use-setoutlineprovider-instead-of-setoutline-in-lollipop