# Add shadow on imageview

Tags: android

I am using imageview in my app,and i want to show shadow effect on my imageview.My imageview is circuler.I searched but did not find perfact solution as i need.
I also tried to use this

https://github.com/sparrow007/CircularImageview lib.

It's working but after adding shadow,shadow is cutting from bottom.I tried to use drawable background and some other library.
Anyone has idea about this.?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use setOutlineProvider instead of setOutline in Lollipop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26472955/how-to-use-setoutlineprovider-instead-of-setoutline-in-lollipop)

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your xml imageview:

```
 android:outlineProvider="background"
```

And set your elevation to your desire

Comment: My image is circuler,so after setting this with elevation,my image is changing in oval and getting out from left and right.