# Floating Action Button for lower version

Tags: android

Is there a way I can Achieve the floating button to work on 4.0 and later android??

I've seen it on google plus but I haven't found any tutorial. Only for android l preview. What did google+ use to achieve it?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Finally with the Material Design support Library v 22.2.0 the FloatingActionButton is available. Check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30483210/is-there-a-native-component-for-the-floating-action-button-in-android-material-d/30527761#30527761

Answer (score 10):

You can now use the [FloatingActionButton](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/FloatingActionButton.html) from the support-design library. Add this dependency to your gradle build file:

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
```

And then add the FloatingActionButton to your layout file:

```
 <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_done" />
```

Example project from Chris Banes: https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare.

Answer (score 7):

I created an open-source library called [FloatingActionButton](https://github.com/makovkastar/FloatingActionButton). It's a Google+ like floating action button which reacts on the list view scrolling events. Becomes visible when the list view is scrolled up and invisible when scrolled down. API level 14+.

[image: Demo]

Comment: Consider making the 'floating action button' to do just that, float, over the content. You are breaking design guidelines by gluing it to the content below.
No intents to bash your library, the fab looks great.

Comment: You may just add it without attaching to the scrollable content. In this case the FAB will not react on scrolling events.

Comment: How can i use your library for Eclipse? @makovkastar

Comment: @PandiriDeepak you may add this library as a Maven or Gradle depedency. There are Maven and Gradle plugins exist for Eclipse as I know.

Answer (score 4):

Here is one aditional free [Floating Action Button library for Android](https://github.com/Scalified/fab)
It has many customizations and requires SDK version 9 and higher

[image]

[Full Demo Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=skSApXvi4xM)

```java
dependencies {
    compile 'com.scalified:fab:1.1.2'
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Original post [is here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25098626/1891118).

You can use [this library](https://github.com/shamanland/floating-action-button), it works well from the Android 2.1, API level 7.

It's so easy to include it in your project:

**build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.shamanland:fab:0.0.6'
}
```

**layout.xml**

```
<com.shamanland.fab.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/your_image"
    />
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use this demo [FloatingView](https://github.com/scabilbao/FloatingView). This demo work from API 11.

Here put all the parts necessary to implement by code. [FloatingView by steps](https://gist.github.com/scabilbao/4a1be92a79abd38ac5c0)

Comment: How do I make something like that : http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-Vv4SxVSI2DY/VEqQxAf3PWI/AAAAAAAAA7c/mfq7XBrIGgo/s400/activity_transitions%2B(1).gif (taken from here: http://android-developers.blogspot.co.il/2014/10/implementing-material-design-in-your.html ) ? does the support library have this feature somewhere? It's also called "Flexible space with image" : http://www.google.com/design/spec/patterns/scrolling-techniques.html#scrolling-techniques-scrolling

Answer (score -1):

Try this library, https://github.com/navasmdc/MaterialDesignLibrary

It can be easily to adapt to your project using Android Studio