# floating action button backward compatibility issue

Tags: android, xml, floating-action-button, android-4.1-jelly-bean

So I'm making an app with several floating action buttons, although in my case they are fixed in the view, but I like the way they look

Anyhow, it seems that for older API such as jelly bean it has issues showing up as the attached image, but it kitkat and later it is shown perfectly, any ideas how to fix this ?

xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="ly.bsagar.libyanaguid.services">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/internetService"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_large" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_public_black_24dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:gravity="center">

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="ActInternet"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_done_black_24dp" />

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="DisInternet"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_clear_black_24dp" />

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="getSetting"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_settings_black_24dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/callWaiting"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_large" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_phone_paused_black_24dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:gravity="center">

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="actwaiting"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_done_black_24dp" />

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="deactwaiting"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_clear_black_24dp" />

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="statuswaiting"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_error_outline_black_24dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/missedCallNotification"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_medium" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_phone_missed_black_24dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:gravity="center">

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:onClick="actmissed"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_done_black_24dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="deactmissed"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_clear_black_24dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

[bad view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BiaPi.png)

[good view (ignore that square, I was testing something](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vlgUp.jpg)

thanks in advance

Comment: Set height to wrap_content on the FABs. Remove the weight.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I don't know what issue you're facing but it might be problem with backward compatibility of this view.

You may try this aditional free [Floating Action Button library for Android](https://github.com/shell-software/fab)
It has many customizations and requires SDK version 9 and higher

[image]

[Full Demo Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=skSApXvi4xM)

Also if possible downgrade (if you're using newer version) Google's Design libray in `build.gradle` file

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
```

More solutions you would find here:

[How to create a floating action button (FAB) in android, using AppCompat v21?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26963219/how-to-create-a-floating-action-button-fab-in-android-using-appcompat-v21)

[Floating Action Button for lower version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24605116/floating-action-button-for-lower-version/25739038#25739038)

Hope it help

Comment: I am trying to understand best practice for material design. I have an app that functions, but certain material components do not apply on different devices running the various API. Is there a tutorial / resource you recommend?