# android - FloatingActionButton not showing on API 16

Tags: android, floating-action-button

I am using a `FloatingActionButton` in my Layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="61dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    app:fabSize="mini"
    android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star_big_off"
    android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton"
    app:layout_anchor="@+id/container"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
    />
```

I put an Image in it when the `Activity` is created:

```
favbtn = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.floatingActionButton);
favbtn.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), btn_star_big_on));
```

When testing on an older Device, such as API 16, the Button is not showing/not visible. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Floating Action Button for lower version](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24605116/floating-action-button-for-lower-version)

Comment: what is version of design library, you are using?

Comment: dependencies:
`dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.8.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}`

Answer (score 2):

Fixed it with favbtn.bringToFront()