# Java android FloatingActionButton API 19 doesn't see

Tags: java, android, api

On samsung galaxy s4 mini I don't see a `FloatingActionButton` but on samsung galaxy s6 (API 23) I see this buttons. This is how I add this buttons :

```
  <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/qick_menu_bt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/quick_menu"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/mapview"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end" />


    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/lista"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/mapview"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|left|end" />
```

In Android Studio Preview I see this buttons , but on phone I don't see . And this I add in build.gradle :

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
```

Comment: Are you sure the positioning of these buttons are appropriate for the device you are testing on?

Comment: It was added in api 22.2.0 therefore it is not visible in api 19. If you want to use for that you can use third party libraries

Comment: @KamranAhmed please look this is what I have in Android Studio : http://static.pokazywarka.pl/i/j/s/c65b642750789c7ae47091eb8d65c058_orig.jpg

Comment: @VivekMishra so what I should to do ?

Comment: @KrzysztofPokrywka here is your answer- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24605116/floating-action-button-for-lower-version

Comment: https://github.com/Clans/FloatingActionButton use this

Comment: @vivek-mishra The design support library is there to provide backward compatibility down to API 9. As mentioned in the question, KrzysztofPokrywka is using it from the support library (android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton).  It was added in design library v22.2.0, and as KrzysztofPokrywka mentioned he is using v23.0.1.

Comment: @KamranAhmed https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/FloatingActionButton.html. Visit this link  and from api level select 19. This class will be grayed out.

Comment: @vivek-mishra The reason for that is an app with target 19 cannot work with design library v22.2.0, it will have to target API 22+.

Comment: @KamranAhmed so what I should change ?

Comment: @KamranAhmed Ok I got your point but ultimately to use it can't be used in with target 19 right?

Comment: The target API should be 21+ for this library to be used, as in the case of KrzysztofPokrywka's code, to use the design library of v23.0.1, the target SDK version in the gradle file should be set as 23.

Comment: @KrzysztofPokrywka What is the theme that you are using? Is it a descendent of `Theme.AppCompat`?

Comment: @KamranAhmed I use a AppTheme.NoActionBar

Comment: You may try changing it to `Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar` and see if it helps.

Comment: @KamranAhmed it doesn't help ...

Comment: @VivekMishra I do what you give me in link and in my project I don't see this buttons

Answer (score -1):

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/FloatingActionButton.html

As mentioned in the android documentation FAB is added in API 21 and above, So you have to made it customized for API 19 but that is not the recommended way

Use this might be it will works

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
```

Comment: How I can   customized for API 19  ?

Comment: The design support library is there to provide backward compatibility. As mentioned in the question, @KrzysztofPokrywka is using it from the support library (`android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton`).

Comment: So what I have to do ?