# How do I position floating action button on top of two views(a map fragment and a linearlayout)

Tags: android, button, position, action, floating

[image]

I want to achieve the positioning of the views. Floating action button on top of two views wherein half of the button overlaps each of the view. Can someone please help me with the xml?

Comment: It is answered here.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24459352/how-can-i-add-the-new-floating-action-button-between-two-widgets-layouts

Comment: You need to post more info about your layout. The solution will vary depending on your layout type.

Answer (score 1):

helpful positioning properties:

```
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right|end"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
```