# Create a Login layout Android Studio

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I would like to create a login layout with EditText that have this feature as I do?! http://s26.postimg.org/ty6otnnll/screencap.png

Thanks for the help and sorry for my bad English

Comment: Have you attempted to write the code?
Hai provato a scrivere il codice?

Comment: i think its called a floating action button..search will be more helpfull and constructive for you.

Comment: @Fondesa +1 for the translation. (Keep in mind, this is an english site).

Comment: @JaredBurrows I know, infact i posted also the same phrase in english!

Comment: This stackoverflow question should give you some insight: http://stackoverflow.com/q/24459352/1400421

Comment: That is the "next" key in the Lollipop keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem, including the properties dell'editText, I gave "textPassword"