# Anchor an floating button on a cardview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-cardview, floating-action-button

I try to anchor an floating button on a cardview without success.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="2dp">


            ..... my view ...


    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/card_view"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end|right"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:clickable="true"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

The result is like this :

[image]

I want that floating button appear like the green circle.
This layout is used in RecyclerView

Is it a way to achieve this ?

Comment: Just add this line in your FloatingActionButton   android:layout_gravity="center|bottom|right",If it not worked i'll help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you add below code your floating button

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="297dp"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout">


    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"

        android:background="@android:color/white"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="2dp">


        ..... my view ...


    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</RelativeLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"
    android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="165dp"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/relativeLayout"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
```

Comment: It didn't the trick i have the floating button on the right but not anchored on the cardview border like green circle.

Answer (score 1):

Before posting a question doa bit a googling, on the second result was this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31240563/5810310)

**EDIT**

I implemented this in a separate project and it works fine...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="The Android Support Library package is a set of code libraries that provide backward-compatible versions of Android framework APIs as well as features that are only available through the library APIs. Each Support Library is backward-compatible to a specific Android API level. This design means that your applications can use the libraries' features and still be compatible with devices running Android 1.6 (API level 4) and up." />

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/cv"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="right|end|bottom"
    android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
    android:clickable="true"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: you gotta be missing something, this code alone behaves exactly as you need and we expect

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the entire layout in a `CoordinatorLayout` and define your anchor to the card view.

```
app:layout_anchor="@id/card_view"
app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end|right"
```

Then it should work.