# Designing Toolbar and using Floating Action Buttons

Tags: android, android-animation, material-design, android-toolbar, floating-action-button

Although there is *some* information on the Internet on more or less how the extended `Toolbar` works and how you are meant to add different `View`s to it, I would like to have a step-by-step guide for me and everyone else who wants to **implement the *extended* `Toolbar` into their apps** (specifically, **how to add views** to the `Toolbar`, what measurements I should use for **margins** between different `View`s and the `Toolbar`, etc.

If possible, I would also like to implement [floating action buttons](http://www.google.co.uk/design/spec/components/buttons-floating-action-button.html#) and some of the material design animations as I can't see any classes or built in methods for this in Android.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

---

## **UPDATE:**

*After Google I/O 2015, you can use the [Design Support Library](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html) to achieve the material design views such as the Floating Action Button (FAB). The `Toolbar` would still be created using the v7 Support Library as shown below.*

---

## Designing the `Toolbar`:

Looking at [these specifications and guidelines from Google](http://www.google.com/design/spec/layout/metrics-keylines.html#metrics-keylines-keylines-spacing), I managed to setup my extended `Toolbar` how I wanted using the correct specifications and measurements.

In my case, I was using `Fragment`s to change the main content (where the `Views` inside the extended `Toolbar` would also be different), so I had a layout file for the activity, and different layout files for my other fragments. The **layout of my main activity** was:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include android:id="@+id/main_toolbar" layout="@layout/toolbar" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/main_toolbar" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

The `@layout/toolbar` simply referred to the following layout (**the layout I was using for a standard Toolbar** (i.e. of normal height, just like an `ActionBar`)):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

And the content in the `FrameLayout` (in the layout for the main activity) would be changed in Java. One of my fragments needed two `Spinner`s and I wanted to embed these into an extended `Toolbar`. The `Toolbar`, conveniently, can be used as a `ViewGroup`, so I created and used the following **layout for one of my fragments**:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/extended_toolbar"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:contentInsetStart="72dp"
        app:contentInsetEnd="16dp"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" >

            <include layout="@layout/toolbar_space_margin" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinner_one"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinner_two
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"/>

            <include layout="@layout/toolbar_space_margin" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/extended_toolbar" >

        <!-- The main content of that activity layout -->

    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The `?attr/colorPrimary` refers to the primary colour (`colorPrimary`), which I defined in `styles.xml`. The two attributes `contentInsetStart` and `contentInsetEnd` I think are like padding for the `Toolbar`. This means that the `LinearLayout` will be `72dp` from the left edge of the `Toolbar` and will be also `16dp` from the right edge of it. Also, I had referenced twice `@layout/toolbar_space_margin` which was the basically **an empty view I had used for the top and bottom margins**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Space
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="16dp" />
```

## Using Floating Action Buttons:

As for using Floating Action Buttons, I found various tutorials and a [Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24459352/how-can-i-add-the-new-floating-action-button-between-two-widgets-layouts) about this, so I used those. I should've researched that part of the question a little better...

**I hope others who came across this issue with design will find this answer useful.**

Answer (score 1):

[Heree](http://www.android4devs.com/2014/12/how-to-make-material-design-app.html) is a nice tutorial on How to work with the brand new Toolbar.

After integrating the toolbar into your Activity, you could be able to add menu items as usual.(through onCreateOptionMenu() and also through xxx_menu.xml)

and... [Here](http://www.android4devs.com/2015/03/how-to-make-floating-action-button-fab.html) is a tutorial about the FAB aka Floating-Action-Button.

Comment: Thanks, but the two tutorial links are the same. Could you update the link for the tutorial on using the `Toolbar` and being able to extend it.

Comment: Thanks again. However I was wondering more specifically on how to implement the extended toolbar, with child views and how to position them.