# Attach floating action button to element

Tags: java, android, material-design, floating-action-button

I am trying to attach a floating action button (fab) to an element, as seen in this image.[image: a google material component page]

I am using Shell Software's library (https://github.com/shell-software/fab). My XML consists of a RelativeLayout inside a Scrollview. Inside the relativelayout is an imageview and a textview. I want my fab to rest on the border of the imageview.

Thanks,

Geffen Avraham

Comment: You should be able to do this just by setting offset in the RelativeLayout

Comment: I have managed to do this but it only works well on lollipop devices. The button appears in a different location depending on the version of android.

Comment: If it's solved, could someone suggest a link or provide code to solve it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I add the new "Floating Action Button" between two widgets/layouts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24459352/how-can-i-add-the-new-floating-action-button-between-two-widgets-layouts)