# How to pin "Floating Action Button" correcly using CoordinatorLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, floating-action-button, android-coordinatorlayout

I use `CoordinatorLayout` as my root view. It contains a `RelativeLayout` and a `FloatingActionButton`. When I set `layout_anchor` and `layout_anchorGravity` for the `FloatingActionButton`, it's not centered on the edge of the `RelativeLayout` (orange area on the screen) as I expected.

I tried solution from this question [How can I add the new "Floating Action Button" between two widgets/layouts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24459352/how-can-i-add-the-new-floating-action-button-between-two-widgets-layouts) but without success.

**Here is my layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/primary_area"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/primary"
        android:paddingBottom="30dp">

        <com.vocabularyminer.android.android.view.view.FloatingEditText
            android:id="@+id/edittext_package_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="14dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:hint="Test fab button"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_done_white_24dp"
        app:elevation="4dp"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/primary_area"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**Result screen:**
[image: Result screen according to the layout file above]

**What I have expected:**

[image]

Comment: What is your question exactly? Where do you want to place it?

Comment: i think your code is correct, once try with EditText instead of your custom edittext.

Comment: I have tried your code with EditText and it works perfectly

Comment: I have added the screen, what I have exactly expected from the layout above. If you look on the answer for this question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30990661/2268063) you can see fab's center is exactly on the bottom edge of the purple area.

Answer (score 0):

I am used to do the anchoring myself by this code, to add in the addOnLayoutChangeListener listener of your main view:

```
// fabGap is the right margin from the CoordinatorLayout
// container is your CoordinatorLayout  

final FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Gravity.TOP);
    layoutParams.setMargins(mAppBarLayout.getRight() - (2 * fabSize) - (2 * fabGap), mAppBarLayout.getBottom() - (fabSize / 2), 0, fabPadding);

    mFavoriteActionButton = new FloatingActionButton(getActivity());
```

Comment: The solution with _CoordinatorLayout_ and *app:layout_anchor* should work without these workarounds. I finally founded, where my problem was and now it's working exactly as I exptected.

Answer (score 0):

I found what was my problem. Solution to this question: [How can I add the new "Floating Action Button" between two widgets/layouts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24459352/how-can-i-add-the-new-floating-action-button-between-two-widgets-layouts) is **correct**. But I placed my fragment to FrameLayout, which was defined according to this xml:

```
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/floating_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

And because I used **wrap_content** then FAB button was placed inside the RelativeLayout instead of the position on the edge of the RelativeLayout.

When I used also in **layout_heigh** parameter **match_parent** then everything works as expected.