# Android Floating Action Button options Menu

Tags: android, android-layout, speed-dial

[image]

There are lots of custom libraries for achieving the FAB menu thing. But I want it to be done without using any custom libraries. I want to achieve this FAB Menu natively.

Please don't suggest me any custom library

Comment: Currently this feature is not supported by official FAB. You'll have to implement it yourself or use some library.

Comment: What libraries may produce this type of FAB?

Answer (score 3):

You can go for android's design library. add this gradle in to your build file

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
```

and follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24459352/how-can-i-add-the-new-floating-action-button-between-two-widgets-layouts) link, which is a stackoverflow link tells how to use. and [this is](http://developer.android.com/samples/FloatingActionButtonBasic/index.html) the link of an sample app.

Example :

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_done"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/viewA"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"/>
```

you can create multiple fab and play with its visibility

**UPDATE**

I think you have to use third party library to do this. please go through [this](https://github.com/Clans/FloatingActionButton) library, this might help you

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: @MangeshGhotage what do you suggest then ?

Comment: the support library is hardly a "custom" library.  it is an extension created to avoid bloating the core app, unless necessary.

Comment: @tonygil but I think OP refers custom library to third party library.

Answer (score 0):

add this dependency to the app build.gradle

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0' 
 compile 'com.github.clans:fab:1.6.2'
```

Add follow the below link [Floating Action Menu](http://www.viralandroid.com/2016/02/android-floating-action-menu-example.html)

Comment: the library has been discontinued for a while now

Answer (score 0):

You could do this natively using visibility... 
Each press on the FAB (ImageView) will toggle visibility with an animation.

I won't write a working sample code, but this should be enough info to help implement a custom floating action button in this way.

XML

```
android:onClick="fabMainClicked"
```

JAVA

```
public void fabMainClicked(View view) 
{
    ImageView fabDrop1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.fabDrop1);
    ImageView fabDrop2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.fabDrop2);
    if (fabDrop1.getVisibility() == fabDrop1.GONE)
    {
        fabDrop1.setVisibility(fabDrop1.VISIBLE);
        fabDrop2.setVisibility(fabDrop2.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

Each ImageView will need to be animated via a custom animator to slide up or onto the screen.

Each ImageView will use a res/drawable as the background to provide a circle and a res/drawable for the center image.

Scale type should be set to center.

Good luck.