# Android:Cannot resolve symbol 'fav' & 'toolbar'

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am newbie to Android & I am trying to build an app but it shows me error that `Cannot resolve symbol 'fav'` & `Cannot resolve symbol 'toolbar'` when I am running it. The 'Fav' & 'toolbar' is present in java file .

My java file is

**LoginActivity.java**

```
package com.example.name.instantly;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_login, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

My **build.gradle** file is

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.name.instantly"
    minSdkVersion 9
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-  rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
}
```

**Activity_login.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.name.instantly.LoginActivity.LoginActivity"
    android:contextClickable="true"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:id="@+id/rootView">

    <!-- Login progress -->


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/mainView"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/loginItemsContainer">

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="phone"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/phone"
                android:text="Email"
                style="@style/AppTheme"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:autoText="false"
                android:ellipsize="none"
                android:editable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:background="@drawable/layout_styles"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp" />


            <EditText
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/password"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:text="Password"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:editable="true"
                android:elegantTextHeight="true"
                android:background="@drawable/layout_styles"
                android:textSize="20sp"

                android:singleLine="false"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Login"
                android:id="@+id/loginbtn"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:enabled="false"
                android:background="@drawable/layout_styles"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:textColor="#0b0a0a"
                android:textSize="20sp"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Where I am going wrong ? Any suggestion?

Comment: Is `toolbar` and `fab` present in `activity_login` xml file?

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
```

Then

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
```

After that **Clean-Rebuild-Restart-Sync Your Project** .

IF NOT WORKS YOU CAN SHARE YOUR `activity_login.xml`

Need to include `Toolbar` Like this

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="Set Your Style" />
```

And

```
 <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:src="@drawable/Your_Icon"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"/>
```

Comment: I am sharing the ActivityLogin.xml in the question itself since the soln u gave doesn't worked...

Comment: @Mani where is `toolbar` ? need to include on it

Comment: @Mani Please rectify your xml

Comment: @Mani Have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24459352/how-can-i-add-the-new-floating-action-button-between-two-widgets-layouts

Answer (score 0):

Add below dependencies

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
```

in your `build.gradle`