# How to make FloatingActionButton "break an edge"

Tags: android, android-layout

By "breaking an edge" I am referring to the [Google design guidelines](https://www.google.com/design/spec/layout/structure.html#structure-ui-regions). A FAB "breaks an edge" when it is positioned between two adjacent elements.

I want my FAB to be positioned between my toolbar and my content view. But right now it is appearing fully on top of the content view:

[image: anchored FAB]

My FAB is anchored to the toolbar. Here is the code:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/toolbar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />
```

In examples I have seen [here](http://saulmm.github.io/mastering-coordinator/) this is how its supposed to be done. You anchor the FAB to the toolbar and then set the anchor gravity to `bottom|right|end`

What am i doing wrong??

Comment: You should not anchor FAB on Toolbar.

Comment: How should i achieve the desired effect then?

Comment: The accepted answer here works for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24459352/how-can-i-add-the-new-floating-action-button-between-two-widgets-layouts

Comment: Please check my answer if you want to achieve this with AppBarLayout.

Comment: Does not work for me, i have copied it exactly.

Comment: @jimmy0251 where is your answer??

Comment: It's given below http://stackoverflow.com/a/34710674/2212847

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should anchor `FAB` to the `AppBarLayout` instead of `Toolbar`. For some reason though, anchoring works only if `AppBarLayout`'s height is more than two times of `ActionBar`'s height. Final code would be like this.

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="168dp"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/appbar"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end" />
```

Comment: wow, this worked. Why do I need to specify a static height for the `AppBarLayout`? This will cause problems for me later on.

Comment: It's not static height, it can be anything more than two times of ActionBar's height. FAB hides automatically for anything less than it.

Comment: If you want your `AppBarLayout`'s height set to `wrap_content`, as an ugly hack, you can set `AppBarLayout`'s `minHeight` to `1dp`.

Answer (score 1):

You need a `CoordinatorLayout` like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:card="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/rootLayout"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="380dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />


        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <!-- ListView or NestedScrollView or RecyclerView etc.. -->

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        app:layout_anchor="@+id/appbar"
        app:elevation="6dp"
        app:borderWidth="0dp"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end" />  

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: What is the purpose of a `CollapsingToolbarLayout`?

Comment: If you want your toolbar extends like https://www.google.it/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiOiPnyjqDKAhUBERQKHV6gAiMQjRwIBw&url=http%3A%2F%2Fd-codepages.com%2Fcollapsing-toolbar-android-example%2F&psig=AFQjCNF8xDC0r0ZWSqe485yD5RIYQiK59A&ust=1452545257690623