# Android - How to place fab-menu(from yavski library) between 2 layouts

Tags: android, android-studio, layout, floating-action-button

I'm using floating action menu from yavski [library](https://github.com/yavski/fab-speed-dial) and I tried to place it between 2 layout just like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24459352/how-can-i-add-the-new-floating-action-button-between-two-widgets-layouts) question:

But when I did it with fab - menu from yavski library, it did not work...

What should I do?

**EDIT**

I'm adding the button between header and "cardview"([link](http://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-working-with-card-view-and-recycler-view/)).

[image]

When I slide down in this and I use default library for fab, it works well (Button disappear and appear when slide up). But when I use the special one, it at start looks good, but when i slide down, instead of disappearing it slides down too...

[image]

And the last problem is, that when the button is clicked, it moves a bit upwards...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

*"A simple library marrying together FAB + ..."*

I dont use this special library your mentioned but with the default one it works like this and if the guy that created the projected worked well it should too:

```
 <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:background="@color/white">

                    //Content

                </LinearLayout>

                <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                    android:id="@+id/fab"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:onClick="process"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_add"
                    app:layout_anchor="@id/ANCHOR_VIEW"
                    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
                    app:backgroundTint="@color/accent"/>

            </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: for this special case you should use the issues section in the github project. https://github.com/yavski/fab-speed-dial/issues