# Android:How can Create This(Bottom Sheet Like Google Map)?

Tags: android, bottom-sheet

How can Create This(Bottom Sheet Like Google Map)?
[image]

[image]

I use [THIS](https://github.com/Flipboard/bottomsheet) component but in fragment I can not handle parallax layout for hide toolbar.

Comment: `I need completed code.Please Help Me!` This community is not a service to write your code for you. If you have a specific problem, there are people here who will happily help you, but you have to show some effort by yourself and not only ask us to write your code.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `RelativeLayout` which will contain your mapview fragment. 
Use `CardView` and set it to bottom. In that `CardView` you can display what you wish to add. For the Travel button use Floating Action button and set `layout_anchorGravity` to `bottom|right|end`

You can also check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24459352/how-can-i-add-the-new-floating-action-button-between-two-widgets-layouts)