# Struggling with CoordinatorLayout anchor

Tags: android, layout, android-coordinatorlayout

I have went through every question on Stack Overflow to place a view at the intersection of two layouts (ultimate question: [How can I add the new "Floating Action Button" between two widgets/layouts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24459352/how-can-i-add-the-new-floating-action-button-between-two-widgets-layouts?noredirect=1&lq=1)) but I am seeing strange behavior while using the suggested answer.

My circularView always gets placed at top left corner of cardView, and I am not sure why this is happening. Please find the xml below:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.phandaarpit.androidrecyclertutorial.MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        app:cardCornerRadius="5dp">

        <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/im_pic"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="150dp"
                    android:background="?attr/colorControlHighlight"
                    />
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/profile_title"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Hello World!" />
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/profile_sub_title"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Hello World!" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:elevation="2dp"
                app:layout_anchor="@id/im_pic"
                app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|left"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

I am trying to populate this view into RecyclerView and i am getting the below output. FAB is completely out of order on some and placed correctly on some.

[image: Output from the code]

Comment: Those `layout_anchor*` attributes won't work inside the `CardView` itself. They'll only work on `View`s that are direct children of the `CoordinatorLayout`. Move the `CircularImageView` to outside of the `CardView` tags.

Comment: @MikeM. can i use coordinatorLayout inside cardview itself and then use  anchor tags?

Comment: Oh, I see what you're trying to do, now. Apologies. I thought you were trying to anchor to the `CardView`. You could put the `CoordinatorLayout` inside a `CardView`, but you might have to rearrange your overall layout. The anchor `View` should be a child of the `CoordinatorLayout`, too.

Comment: Tried that as well @Mike M but doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: also, do the view, to which i will anchor and the one i am anchoring, need to be the direct child of coordinatorLayout?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant by the last sentence in my comment. Sorry if that was ambiguous.

Comment: Well, hang on. Maybe that behavior has changed with a newer support library version. Have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30990661.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134283/discussion-between-kungfu-panda-and-mike-m).